# почему при записи функции без скобок, выводится адрес функции

Tags: c++, visual-studio, компиляция

почему при записи функции без скобок, при попытке вывода выводится адрес функции, не выводится ошибка или что-нибудь такое, а полный адрес в котором хранится функция

Comment: В C++ при обращении к функции без использования скобок, компилятор интерпретирует имя функции как указатель на функцию. Таким образом, выводя значение функции без вызова её с использованием скобок, вы получите адрес функции.

Comment: функция не может иметь значение. И передаваться как аргумент она может только по своему адресу. по-этому `fun` автоматически преобразуется в `& fun`.